# adding comments to rails public activity rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, comments

i have followed Ryan Bates tutorial on public activity, (the gem) and it works well... what i

want is how can i set up a commenting system so that when a user creates for instance a post

which is shown to all his/her friends as an activity i want to place a comment under each

activity so that user can comment on the activity and also i want the comment to belong to a

user.

the view for my activity index is thus

```
<% @activities.each do |activity| %>
    <div class="activity">

      <b style="text-transform: capitalize;">
        <%#= link_to activity.owner.username, activity.owner if activity.owner %></b>

      <%#= link_to image_tag(activity.owner.image.url(:small)) ,activity.owner%>
      <%= render_activity activity %>
    </div>

<% end %>
```

and i have created the various partials for the controller am tracking their activity an example is

```
<div class="media social-box">

  <a class="pull-left social-users-avatars" href="#">
    <%= link_to image_tag(activity.owner.image.url(:small)) ,activity.owner%>
    <p><%= link_to activity.owner.username, activity.owner if activity.owner %>
      <span style="font-size: 11px; color:green;">updated status</span> </p>

  </a>



  <ul class="unstyled custumer_say">
    <li class="clearfix">
      <%=  image_tag(activity.trackable.image.url,:style=> "width: 30%; padding-right: 10px;", :class=> "pull-left img_client")%>
      <%#= image_tag @post.image_url, :style=> "width: 37%; padding-right: 10px;", :class=> "pull-left img_client" %>
      <div class="entry-content">
        <header>


          <span class="entry-date">&mdash;  <%=  activity.updated_at.strftime("%I:%M  %P %b%d" ) %> </span>

        </header>
        <p><%= activity.trackable.details %></p>


      </div>

    </li>
  </ul><!-- End Testimonaila list-->
```

so i would love to put the comments for this activity under it.....

Comment: i have figured it out .... took a lot though

Comment: Hey! Could you tell us how you figured it out? Been struggling with this for a while now? Thanks!